# how to Install Ioncube 10.4

Tags: php, xampp, ioncube

Hi Everybody I want to install ioncube 10.4 on xampp with php 8

how to do it ?

when i go to loader-wizard get me this error :

```
IMPORTANT: Ensure that This Script Is Removed When No Longer Required
ionCube Loader Wizard

Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in D:\Projects\Website\main\htdocs\loader-wizard.php:2400 Stack trace: #0 D:\Projects\Website\main\htdocs\loader-wizard.php(2400): file_get_contents('') #1 D:\Projects\Website\main\htdocs\loader-wizard.php(2487): get_loader_strings('') #2 D:\Projects\Website\main\htdocs\loader-wizard.php(3428): loader_compatibility_test('') #3 D:\Projects\Website\main\htdocs\loader-wizard.php(3511): correct_loader_wrong_location() #4 D:\Projects\Website\main\htdocs\loader-wizard.php(3158): ini_loader_warnings() #5 D:\Projects\Website\main\htdocs\loader-wizard.php(2939): loader_not_installed() #6 D:\Projects\Website\main\htdocs\loader-wizard.php(2743): default_page() #7 D:\Projects\Website\main\htdocs\loader-wizard.php(115): run() #8 {main} thrown in D:\Projects\Website\main\htdocs\loader-wizard.php on line 2400
```

Comment: i'm using wordpress

Comment: There is no Loader for PHP 8 yet and you wouldn't need PHP 8 unless you have scripts that cannot run on PHP 7. So it's best to use the latest PHP 7.4.